# assigning objects from array to google maps markers - objective C/iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can't figure out how to add objects from my `NSMutableArray` to google maps markers. I've already setup the map etc and it works fine, it just crashes at the line

```
NSString *lat = [[array objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0];
```

**error: reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x359158'**

if the objectAtIndex:i is equal to =, so first object. any idea why?

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"21.282778, -157.829444",@"21.292778, -157.829444", nil];
NSMutableArray *markersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++){



NSString *lat = [[array objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *lon = [[array objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1];
double lt=[lat doubleValue];
double ln=[lon doubleValue];
NSString *name = [[array objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:2];
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.appearAnimation=YES;
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lt,ln);
marker.title = name;
marker.snippet = [[array objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:3];
marker.map = mapView_;

[markersArray addObject:marker];

}
```

thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array` is an array of `NSString` objects, but this line -

`NSString *lat = [[array objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0];`

treats it as an array of arrays - ie. you are trying to retrieve the object at index 0 from the result of retrieving the object at index `i` from `array`.  Because the object at index `i` of `array` is an `NSString` and `NSString` doesn't have an `objectAtIndex` method you get the exception.

You could use

```
NSMutableArray *array=@[@{@"lat":@"21.282778",@"lon":@"-157.829444",@"name":@"marker 1"},@{@"lat":@"21.292778",@"lon":@"-157.829444",@"name":@"marker2"}];
```

and then you will have an array of `NSDictionaries`, and your dictionaries will contain lat, lon and name keys.

Then your loop can use

```
for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++){


NSDictionary *markerDict=[array objectAtIndex:i]
NSString *lat = [markerDict objectForKey:@"lat"];
NSString *lon = [markerDict objectForKey:@"lon"];
double lt=[lat doubleValue];
double ln=[lon doubleValue];
NSString *name = [markerDict objectForKey:@"name"];
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.appearAnimation=YES;
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lt,ln);
marker.title = name;
marker.snippet = [[array objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:3];
marker.map = mapView_;

[markersArray addObject:marker];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"21.282778, -157.829444",@"21.292778, -157.829444", nil];
```

Look at your array. It an 1D array not an array of array.

```
NSString *lat = [[array objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *lon = [[array objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1];
```

By the above two lines you are pointing to an array of array (2D array). You can do something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<[array count]/2;i++){
    NSString *lat = [[array objectAtIndex:(i*2)];
    NSString *lon = [[array objectAtIndex:(i*2+1)];
}
```

Hope this helps .. :)

Comment: thanks for your reply, pretty new to objective C so completely forgot about 2D arrays. Cheers!